# Angular $scope not updating in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, ionic-framework

I have tried so many answers to this question, but nothing works.

**The bug**: Right now when the total data items added meets the item requirement, the item is removed from the list, but the list isn't refreshing the view with the item removed in the select dropdown or child list.

I assume there is something specific to my code, so I've recreated my functionality here:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, filterFilter) {

  Array.prototype.sum = function(prop) {
    var ptotal = 0
    for (var i = 0, _len = this.length; i < _len; i++) {
      ptotal += this[i][prop]
    }
    return ptotal
  }

  $scope.owners = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "parent 1"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "parent 2"
  }];

  $scope.children = [{
    "id": "1",
    "total": "2",
    "owner": "1",
    "name": "child 1"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "total": "2",
    "owner": "2",
    "name": "child 2"
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "total": "1",
    "owner": "2",
    "name": "child 3"
  }];

  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.owners.length);
  $scope.selectedOwner = $scope.owners[random];
  $scope.childrenList = $scope.children.filter(function(x) {
    return x.owner == $scope.selectedOwner.id;
  });

  $scope.remove = function(child) {

  }

  $scope.ownerChange = function(owner) {
    $scope.selectedOwner = owner;
    $scope.childrenList = $scope.children.filter(function(x) {
      return owner.id == $scope.selectedOwner.id;
    });
  }

  $scope.data = [];

  $scope.add = function(child) {
    $scope.totalInit = filterFilter($scope.children, {
      id: child.id
    });
    var total = $scope.totalInit.sum("number");
    var complete = filterFilter($scope.data, {
      id: +child.id
    }).length;
    var number = +complete + 1;
    var input = {
      "id": child.id,
      "name": child.name,
      "number": number
    };
    if (+number >= +child.total) {
      $scope.children = $scope.children.filter(function(x) {
        return x.id != child.id;
      });
      $scope.ownerStatus = filterFilter($scope.data, {
        id: child.id
      }).length;
      if ($scope.ownerStatus === 0) {
        $scope.owners = $scope.owners.filter(function(x) {
          return x.id != child.owner;
        });
      }
    }
    $scope.data.push(input);

  };



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p><b>The bug:</b> Right now when the total data items added meets the item requirement, the item is removed from the list, but the list isn't refreshing the view with the item removed in the select dropdown or child list.</p>
  <p>---------------------------------------------------------</p>
  <b>Select Owner:</b>
  <select ng-options="o.name for o in owners track by o.id" ng-model="selectedOwner" ng-change="ownerChange(selectedOwner)">
  </select>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="c in childrenList">{{c.name}}
      <button ng-click="add(c)">Add</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <b>Data:</b>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="d in data">{{d.name}}
      <button ng-click="data.splice($index, 1)">Remove</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's the issue? The list is not displaying properly when you make changes in the dropdown?

Comment: When I make changes (removing the item from the array), the dropdown options and list aren't updating in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out myself. I needed to call the list filter again after the $scope change to update the lists. Here is the updated code:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, filterFilter, $timeout) {

  Array.prototype.sum = function(prop) {
    var ptotal = 0
    for (var i = 0, _len = this.length; i < _len; i++) {
      ptotal += this[i][prop]
    }
    return ptotal
  }

  $scope.owners = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "parent 1"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "parent 2"
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "parent 3"
  }];

  $scope.children = [{
    "id": "1",
    "total": "2",
    "owner": "1",
    "name": "child 1"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "total": "2",
    "owner": "2",
    "name": "child 2"
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "total": "1",
    "owner": "2",
    "name": "child 3"
  }, {
    "id": "4",
    "total": "5",
    "owner": "3",
    "name": "child 4"
  }, {
    "id": "5",
    "total": "2",
    "owner": "1",
    "name": "child 5"
  }];

  //  var uTotal = $scope.children.sum("total");

  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.owners.length);
  $scope.selectedOwner = $scope.owners[random];
  $scope.childrenList = $scope.children.filter(function(x) {
    return x.owner == $scope.selectedOwner.id;
  });

  $scope.ownerChange = function(owner) {
    $scope.selectedOwner = owner;
    $scope.childrenList = $scope.children.filter(function(x) {
      return x.owner == $scope.selectedOwner.id;
    });
  }

  $scope.data = [];

  $scope.remove = function(child) {
    for (var i3 = $scope.data.length - 1; i3 >= 0; i3--) {
      if ($scope.data[i3].number == child.number && $scope.data[i3].id == child.id) {
        $scope.data.splice(i3, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  $scope.add = function(child) {
    $scope.totalInit = filterFilter($scope.children, {
      owner: child.owner
    });
    var total = $scope.totalInit.sum("total");
    var complete = filterFilter($scope.data, {
      id: +child.id
    }).length;
    var number = +complete + 1;
    var input = {
      "id": child.id,
      "name": child.name,
      "number": number
    };
    if (+number == +child.total) {
      $scope.data.push(input);
      for (var i = $scope.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ($scope.children[i].id == child.id) {
          $scope.children.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
      $scope.childrenList = $scope.children.filter(function(x) {
        return x.owner == $scope.selectedOwner.id;
      });
      $scope.ownerStatus = filterFilter($scope.children, {
        owner: child.owner
      }).length;
      if ($scope.ownerStatus === 0) {
        for (var i2 = $scope.owners.length - 1; i2 >= 0; i2--) {
          if ($scope.owners[i2].id == child.owner) {
            $scope.owners.splice(i2, 1);
          }
        }
        var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.owners.length);
        $scope.selectedOwner = $scope.owners[random2];
        $scope.childrenList = $scope.children.filter(function(x) {
          return x.owner == $scope.selectedOwner.id;
        });
        if ($scope.owners.length === 0) {
          alert("All Trials Complete");
          $scope.children = [];
          $scope.owners = [];
        }
      }

    } else {
      $scope.data.push(input);
    }
  };


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <b>Select Owner:</b>
  <select ng-options="o.name for o in owners track by o.id" ng-model="selectedOwner" ng-change="ownerChange(selectedOwner)">
  </select>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="c in childrenList track by c.id">{{c.name}}
      <button ng-click="add(c)">Add</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <b>Data:</b>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="d in data track by $index">{{d.name}}
      <button ng-click="remove(d, $index)">Remove</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```